# Axes no longer moving Ender 5 Plus

Tags: creality-ender-5, creality, axis

The printer was working fine until the nozzle jammed, so I cleaned it out but accidentally unplugged the BLTouch. I plugged it straight back in again but now none of the axes will move at all, not even manually. The BLTouch lights up still, I’ve checked the connector on it and it all looks fine.

Completely stumped. Any ideas please let me know! Cheers

Comment: Have you checked the BLTouch connections from one end to the other? I had a slightly different problem with my BLTouch and turns out the connector in between was loose. After I rechecked all my wiring everything worked out fine.

Comment: No cigar, all connected up fine. Found a video on YouTube of the same issue but there was no solve posted. Someone said about re-flashing firmware but I’ve never done that.

Comment: https://youtu.be/5drDnH5y1Yc